# Get session value globally in express js for all views

Tags: session, express

I am doing a login page in express js. I want to display the logged in user name in all view pages. I used session to display the name in view pages. It is working but i want to set session value for each rendering page as given below.

Controller:

```
res.render('index.hbs',{data:req.session.username});
```

View(hbs):

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <img src="img/atomix_user31.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
  <span class="hidden-xs">{{data}}</span>
</a>
```

For each rendering page i need to attach value as above i have given. Is there any way to set global variable for accessing the login user name in all pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values passed to the view are merged from 3 sets of values:

1. The object you pass to `render`.
2. `res.locals`.
3. `app.locals`.

You wouldn't put the user's name in `app.locals` because that is shared between all requests but `res.locals` is specific to the current request/response so that could be used:

```
res.locals.data = req.session.username;
res.render('index.hbs');
```

You can then move that first line to somewhere else in the chain. For example, like this:

```
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.data = req.session.username;
    next();
});
```

You'll need to adjust exactly how this route is registered to suit your application. This would need to be placed after the session is populated but before your views are rendered.

See:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a relatively simple code structure I would create a renderer function / module that does all the common tasks that you want done in all views

e.g.:

```
function myRender(req, res, placeholders) {
    var my_locals = {data:req.session.username};
    return res.render('index.hbs', _.merge(my_locals, placeholders));
}
```

If your code is asynchronous and you don't have access to request you could use a module like https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage to store it temporarily.